# Cordova Ios Assets Catalog Compiler error on Xcode 9.4

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework, xcode9.4

I have this error when excecute the cordova app in iphone device:

```
/Users/myuser/Desktop/myionicCordovaproject/platforms/ios/MyprojectName/Images.xcassets: error: Failed to write image data for the launch image set from "LaunchImage.launchimage/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" to "/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProjectName-agddjdisjisxvgbuefjxrhzmruvc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myProjectName.app/LaunchImage-Portrait@2x~ipad.png".
Underlying Errors:
    Description: pngcrush exited with signal '6' for "/Users/myuser/Desktop/myionicCordovaproject/platforms/ios/myProjectName/Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png". 
Error output:
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CFOpenDirectory.framework/Versions/A/CFOpenDirectory
  Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
  Reason: malformed mach-o: load commands size (1533929015) > 32768
```

This error only present with compile the app in phisical devices , in emulator not present error.

My system information:

```
Cordova CLI: 8.0.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 2.0.1
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.1
Ionic Framework Version: 1.2.4-nightly-1917
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.20
ios-deploy version: 2.0.0 
ios-sim version: 7.0.0 
OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
Node Version: v4.8.0  
Xcode version: Xcode 9.4.1 Build version 9F2000
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you haven’t already, make sure to take a look in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Good luck!